How to get lanes and turning movements for an intersection using OSMnx?
Given a latitude and longitude pair of a street intersection, how would I get information about the intersection such as the names of the roads that intersect, the number of lanes each road has, and if any of the lanes are turning lanes?
This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure where to go from here, nor if this is even the right approach.
def get_intersection_turn_movements(lat, lon):
    distance = 100
    
    G = ox.graph_from_point((lat, lon), dist=distance, network_type='drive', simplify=False)
    nearest_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, lon, lat)
    edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)


I'd recommend reading the OSMnx getting started guide and working through the usage examples, as what you're looking to do is its basic functionality. After that if you're stuck you can update your question with more details and context.

Could you please direct me to a relevant example? This would be useful not only to me, but others who visit this question in the future.

An intersection is a graph node. A street is a graph edge. If you have a node of interest and want to inspect its incident edges' attributes, just look at those edges' attribute data dictionaries. https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.edges.html
